# How to write code for copy data if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

code is copying data after every 5 seconds but i want it to copy only if bu8<>0 and if condition is not met then do nothing.

Here is the code

```
Sub UpdateData()
    If Hour(Time) >= 3 And Minute(Time) >= 1 Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:0:5"), "UpdateData", False
    Else
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:0:5"), "UpdateData"
    CopyData
    End If
End Sub
Sub CopyData()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim dCol As Long
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set cRng = sht1.Range("Bu1:bu8")
        dCol = sht2.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        sht2.Range(Cells(2, dCol).Address, Cells(8, dCol + 1).Address) = cRng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: some expert says you have to put event change worksheet but i don't know about it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Range, c As Range
    Dim dCol As Long
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set c = sht1.Range("BU8")

    If c.Value <> 0 and Len(c.Value)>0 Then
        Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set cRng = sht1.Range("Bu1:bu8")
        sht2.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) _
                .Offset(0, 1).Resize(8 ,1).value = cRng.Value

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it gives error runtime 13 mismatch and i want to copy when cell changes it value, as is mentioned value is changing after some second automatically by rand calculate function.